# MyCntrl is not defined on page after using requirejs on controller script files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, requirejs

I am using angular, grunt and bower in my application

I load the javascript files like this in my index.html file:

I define requirejs in Gruntfile as, where `dep1` and `dep2` are other controllers that will be used by `MyCntrl`.

```
requirejs: {
  compile: {
    options: {
      baseUrl: './app',
      removeCombined: true,
      mainConfigFile: './config/config.js',
      include: [ 'scripts/controllers/mycntrl.js''scripts/controllers/dep1.js', 'scripts/controllers/dep2.js' ],
      out: './app/requirejs/appIdeas-combined.js',
uglify2: {
        output: {
            beautify: true
        },
        compress: {
            sequences: false,
            global_defs: {
                DEBUG: false
            }
        },
        warnings: true,
        mangle: false
    },
}
  }
}
```

When I access my application I get

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myCntrl' is not a function, got undefined
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/ng/areq?p0=myCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
```

and when I look at `appIdeas-combined.js` I see this:

```
angular.module("MyApp").controller("MyCntrl", function($rootScope, dep1, dep2) {
    function initialize() {
```

So is it possible to combine all of my controllers into one javascript file?

Once I get this to work I will try to add the other javascript files into this.

Comment: Is it just a case mismatch? `MyCntrl` in the definition and `myCntrl` in the HTML maybe?

Comment: No, I can't show the real names so I just made some up to try to be consistent.